# FFMpeg autorotate video and image output

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video

I have a video which I'm trying to downscale to a video output, and also create a thumbnail image at every 2 seconds using a single FFMpeg command(hardware accelerated). Following is the command:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "inputVideo.mov" -vf "scale_cuda=1280:720,hwdownload,format=nv12,setsar=1:1" -c:v h264_nvenc -profile:v main -level:v 4 -b:v 2500K "outputVideo.mp4" -vf "scale_cuda=160:90,hwdownload,format=nv12, fps=0.5,setsar=1:1" "thumbnailOutputs_%04d.jpg"
```

But the input video has a rotation parameter(180 degrees) in its metadata, and based on the [FFMpeg Documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Video-Options) the command automatically rotates the output. I don't want my outputs to be rotated.

> -autorotate Automatically rotate the video according to file metadata. Enabled by default, use -noautorotate to disable it.

I changed my command to add `-noautorotate`. It fixed the video output, but the image outputs are still getting rotated. I even tried separating the the command for images and using `-noautorotate` but still doesn't work.

Also, an interesting observation is the command behaves differently when i dont use hardware acceleration. Following is a normal cpu based command:

```
ffmpeg  -i "inputVideo.mov" -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level:v 4 -b:v 2500K -vf "scale=1280:720,setsar=1:1" "outputVideo.mp4" -vf fps=0.5 -s 160X90 "thumbnailOutputs_%04d.jpg"
```

Following are the observations:

**Hardware accleration commands (nvenc)**

default command

- video - Upside down❌ (rotated 180 degrees)
- images - Upside down❌ (rotated 180 degrees)

command with -noautorotate flag

- video - Correct✅
- images - Upside down❌ (rotated 180 degrees)

**CPU commands (libx264)**

default command

- video - Correct✅
- images - Correct✅

command with -noautorotate flag

- video - Correct✅
- images - Upside down❌ (rotated 180 degrees)

Link to the input video used: [Input Video used](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1abud5WgIKKnh_ysBlnq1iU0Mj4y0YrLC/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please share a sample input video file (using Google Drive for example)?

Comment: @Rotem I've added in the link to the input video at the end of the question.

Comment: It looks like the command supposed to be `ffmpeg -autorotate -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "inputVideo.mov" -vf "scale_cuda=1280:720,hwdownload,format=nv12,setsar=1:1" -c:v h264_nvenc -profile:v main -level:v 4 -b:v 2500K "outputVideo.mp4" -vf "scale_cuda=160:90,hwdownload,format=nv12, fps=0.5,setsar=1:1" "thumbnailOutputs_%04d.jpg"`. But it's not supported by the hardware accelerated decoder. I think the best option is adding `hflip`,`vflip` filters "manually".

Comment: Try: `ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "inputVideo.mov" -vf "scale_cuda=1280:720,hwdownload,hflip,vflip,format=nv12,setsar=1:1" -c:v h264_nvenc -profile:v main -level:v 4 -b:v 2500K "outputVideo.mp4" -vf "scale_cuda=160:90,hwdownload,hflip,vflip,format=nv12, fps=0.5,setsar=1:1" "thumbnailOutputs_%04d.jpg"`